# Individual contribution of string-length counts in polygons drawn on a clock face

Tags: geometry, trigonometry, necklace-and-bracelets

**Background**

In a psychology experiment we had people interact with various 5-sided polygons drawn on the face of a clock (the specifics of the experiment are not pertinent to the question at hand).

For example, here is the polygon [0 1 3 6 9]:

[image]

**Procedure**

In the experiment, each of 66 possible polygons were scored according to some criterion (again, the specifics aren't relevant to the math).

**Analysis**

We hope to do an analysis that relates the count of different sized strings to the recorded performance for each polygon.

For that reason, we create string-length vectors representing the count of each string length found in each polygon. For instance, in the polygon presented in the example above we find 1 string of length 1 (green), 1 string of length 2 (teal), 4 strings of length 3 (blue), 1 string of length 4 (purple), 1 string of length 5 (red), and 2 strings of length 6 (orange).
So the vector for this polygon is (1 1 4 1 1 2).

- We hope to be able to create an analysis that quantifies each string
  length's count individual contribution to the recorded performance.

**Challenge**

However, the string counts are not independent of one another, such that the presence of certain strings can necessitate or prevent the appearance of certain other strings (as every triangle formed between 3 strings must sum to 12).

We are struggling to come up with a way to disentangle the influence of the strings on one another in order to execute our analysis.

How can we disentangle the co-dependence of the strings such that we could isolate the contribution of the count of each string length in isolation?

**Clarification**

This is a more complex interaction than simply a correlation, because the interactions between the the counts of various string lengths appears to be non-trivial.

Any clever ideas on how we might solve our conundrum?

Thanks!

Comment: I do not see the challenge. As I understood, you want to count individual contribution of each string length's to the recorded performance. I this these string length's contribute because they exist (or are given), and this is essential, whereas the co-dependence concerns the secondary questions why they exist or how they exist together.

Comment: I didn't understand your question because of some typos. Could you please edit it when you get a chance? Thanks!

Comment: I tend to agree with @AlexRavsky (as far as I understand their comment). I don't see how this is different from the standard situation in which statistical analyses of the influence of various factors are performed. One usually doesn't assume that the factors are independent (and they rarely are). If your hypothesis is that the presence of certain string lengths (and not of combinations of string lengths) influences performance, I don't see how your analysis would be affected by the fact that some combinations were excluded in the data.

Comment: I think the fact that the interdependence is completely predictable through geometry what makes me want to disentangle it. Besides we do care about the effect of string combination. Which analysis technique do you think would be effective here?